# About Aync,Promise ,Await

Tags: node.js, async-await, flush-promises

```js
result = {};
Promise.all(data2.map(async function(subcat) {
    await productModel.find({ subcategory_id: subcat._id }, function(err4, data4) {
        result.sub_category = subcat;
        result.product = data4;
    });
    return result;
})).then(www => {
    var records = util.inspect(www, false, null, true /* enable colors */);
    console.log(records);
});
```

I cannot get the result with new object passed.Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Please add your title is more accurate about your certain problem.